# How to post a photo to my facebook ablum with javascript SDK?

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk

I googled around for a few hours about posting photos on FB with JS SDK but have no luck so far. Here is my code, according to `/me/permissions`, I saw "photo_upload: 1 publish_stream: 1" in my console log, so i am quite sure i have the permissions to upload a photo. however, the exception as stated "An unknwon error has occured", am I doing something wrong?

```
//check permissions
FB.api('/me/permissions',function(fbResponse){
      console.log(fbResponse);
});

//post to feed
FB.api("me/feed","post",{
                    message:"wtf - welcome to facebook"
                 },function(fbResponse){
                          if(!fbResponse||fbResponse.error)
                              console.log(fbResponse.error);
                          else 
                              console.log(fbResponse.id);
});

//post to album
FB.api("me/photos","post",{
                    message:"wtf - welcome to facebook",
                    url:"https://my_domain.com/image.jpg"
                },function(fbResponse){
                    if(!fbResponse||fbResponse.error)console.log(fbResponse.error);
                    else console.log(fbResponse.id);
                });
```

Response:

> Object {message: "An unknown error has occurred.", type: "OAuthException", code: 1}

Comment: Is the image url correct? I tested the code and it worked

Comment: Hi Mittal, many thanks for your reply. I have double check the url and it should be correct. BTW, although above code cannot upload a image to my FB album, but it still created a empty ablum.

Comment: just to be clear, the url is https://popket.com/app/bin/img/tmpLayout.jpg and my FB app is based on https://popket.com/app/ , my app is still working as Sandbox Mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I dont know why but something's up with the image that you are using, may be facebook is not able to reach to your domain or what.

If you try any other image, for eg: http://graph.facebook.com/sahilmittal/picture it will work. I myself tried with many images and the post was successful.

May you can report bug regarding post with that particular image [here](http://developers.facebook.com/bugs)

Comment: how to check if facebook is not able to reach my server?

Comment: I think something go wrong with my server but I have no idea at all.

Comment: I found the solution:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20309479/facebook-open-graph-object-debugger-return-nothing-to-my-url

Answer (score 0):

`OAuthException` is caused when there is no authenticated .Check you have a valid user.

Note: FB.api() works only after the login.

Comment: Hi kaar3k, many thanks for your reply. Although above code cannot upload a image, but it still can make a post to my feed and create a empty album, so... yes, I think I have the valid user and the code run after FB.login().