# Facebook Open Graph Object Debugger return nothing to my url

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

This is a very short question but driving me crazy.

Facebook Open Graph Object Debugger return "Could not retrieve data from URL" to my [url](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/object?q=popket.com)!

If I look into [echo](https://developers.facebook.com/tools/debug/og/echo?q=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.popket.com)!... I got nothing at all.
Am I doing something wrong with my server(tomcat)?

Comment: I look into my log file, I find facebook is try to reach my server, but got a http 302 error.
173.252.100.116 - - [01/Dec/2013:07:18:30 +0000] "GET / HTTP/1.1" 302 -

Comment: I opened a thread in https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/632577846802584 , any advice is welcome

Comment: Eventually, I format and rebuild my server, I found if I turn on SSL, FB cannot reach my server.